# What happens if a French citizen goes to Poipet's strip of casinos and hotels between the Cambodian and Thai passport control counters?

Tags: covid-19, thailand, cambodia, french-citizens, casinos

Given that [both Cambodia and Thailand have suspended visa exemptions, visas on arrival and e-visas due to COVID-19](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php), I wonder what happens if a French citizen goes to [Poipet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poipet)'s strip of casinos and hotels between the Cambodian and Thai passport control counters, assuming that they do not have any special visas to enter Cambodia or Thailand. Are they stuck in the strip of casinos and hotels?

---

To save some time for people going through answers in the dupe question, assuming one enters from Thailand: one can enter back Thailand and the Thai departure stamp gets [canceled](https://rompingandnguyening.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/bangkoking-again/):

[image]

No idea whether this still applies during the COVID-19 travel restrictions.

Comment: Note that [the casinos in Poipet are currently closed](https://southeastasiaglobe.com/covid-19-cambodias-border-city-poipet/). I would imagine Thai exit controls would discourage you from making the trip but sources differ on if the land border is fully closed or not, and the answer to that may change with some frequency anyhow.